# Access VBA Classes Arrays

Tags: class, vba, service, web, module

Im trying to use some classes that will hold invoice data and I cant seem to get it working. I just want it to save details of an invoice in an array. Heres the code, maybe someone can figure it out.
Also id like for the LineItems to take a random number of product items, not sure how to do that yet. Im doing this to eventually send the data through a web service from ms access.

Here is the other code for struct_XOrder:

```
Public OrderNumber As String 
Public ClientShortName As String 
'"LineItems" is an array with elements defined as struct_LineItem
'See Complex Types: Arrays in Microsoft Office 2003 Web Services Toolkit Help
'for details on implementing arrays.
Public LineItems As Variant 
Public OrderError As String
```

Heres the struct_LineItem:

```
Public ProductSKU As String 
Public Qty As Long 
Public UnitPrice As Variant 
Public ItemComment As String 
Public ItemError As String
```

Heres my main code

```
Sub webservicetest()

Dim NewOrder As struct_XOrder
Dim LineItems(1 To 2) As Variant
Dim Xline(1 To 2) As Variant

Set Xline() = struct_LineItem

Set NewOrder = New struct_XOrder

Set NewOrder.LineItems() = New struct_LineItem
Set NewOrder.LineItems() = New Xline
'Xline = New struct_LineItem


Xline(1).ItemComment = "items" 
Xline(1).Qty = 10
NewOrder.LineItems() = Xline()


NewOrder.ClientShortName = "DemoClient"
NewOrder.OrderNumber = "12345"

'Xline(1).ItemComment = "item1"
'Xline(1).Qty = 5

Debug.Print NewOrder.ClientShortName
Debug.Print NewOrder.OrderNumber

'For i = LBound(Xline) To UBound(Xline): Debug.Print Xline(i): Next

'Debug.Print Xline(1).ItemComment
'Debug.Print Xline(1).Qty

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

See comments for explanations.

Use `Type` instead within VBA to create structs. Also, you do not need to use `Set` the way you are.

Additionally, use Option Explicit to require variable declarations whenever using VBA unless you want a nightmare.

This all can go in the same module.

---

```
'use this
Option Explicit

'VBA structs are defined like the following
'and do not need "new" (similar to other languages)
'when creating them

Type struct_LineItem
    ProductSKU As String
    Qty As Long
    UnitPrice As Variant
    ItemComment As String
    ItemError As String

End Type

Type struct_XOrder
    OrderNumber As String
    ClientShortName As String

    'make this more clear
    LineItems() As struct_LineItem
    OrderError As String
End Type


Sub webservicetest()

    Dim NewOrder As struct_XOrder
    Dim LineItems(1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim Xline(1 To 2) As struct_LineItem

    'you can't do this, you need to specify which element
    'in XLine you want to set
    'Set Xline() = struct_LineItem

    Dim myStruct As struct_LineItem
    Xline(1) = myStruct

    'you don't need "set"
    NewOrder.LineItems = Xline()

    'this won't update as if it's a reference, btw
    Xline(1).ItemComment = "items"
    Xline(1).Qty = 10
    NewOrder.LineItems = Xline()


    NewOrder.ClientShortName = "DemoClient"
    NewOrder.OrderNumber = "12345"

    Debug.Print NewOrder.ClientShortName
    Debug.Print NewOrder.OrderNumber

    'don't do ":" as this makes code unbearably not readable...
    'For i = LBound(Xline) To UBound(Xline): Debug.Print Xline(i): Next

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(NewOrder.LineItems)
        Debug.Print NewOrder.LineItems(i).ItemComment
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That makes a lot more sense. Il play around with it to get it to do what i want.

Comment: The struct_xorder class module is altered, is there a way i can just keep it as 'lineitems as variant'? Its causing errors. @enderland

Comment: BTY the webservices is at https://webservices.p3pl.com/WSOrder.asmx?WSDL if that helps anyone understand better.